# Function conversion from DB2 to snowflake equivalent

Tags: db2, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can someone please help me to convert this below function according to snowflake equivalent?

DB2 FORMAT :

```
CREATE FUNCTION resign_employee (number CHAR(6))
 RETURNS TABLE (empno CHAR(6),
         salary DOUBLE,
         dept  CHAR(3))
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Purpose: This procedure takes in an employee number, then removes that
--      employee from the EMPLOYEE table.
--      A useful extension to this function would be to archive the
--      original record into an archive table.
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  DECLARE l_salary DOUBLE;
  DECLARE l_job CHAR(3);
 
  SET (l_salary, l_job) = (SELECT salary, job
                FROM OLD TABLE (DELETE FROM employee
                        WHERE employee.empno = number));
 
  RETURN VALUES (number,l_salary, l_job);
 END
```

SNOWFLAKE FORMAT:

```
create function resign_employee (number VARCHAR(6))
    returns table (empno VARCHAR,salary NUMBER,dept VARCHAR)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    AS
    $$
        'select salary, job from old employee'
        'delete from employee where empno=number'
    $$;
```

ERROR AFTER CONVERTION:

```
Compilation of SQL UDF failed: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 3 at position 8 unexpected ''delete from employee where empno=number''.
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?